# .protect stops connections(1).refresh before finishing

Tags: excel, vba

I want to refresh a connection on a protected sheet. Refreshing starts but gets interrupted in the protection-step, so my connection doesn't finish its update. 
I already searched for hours.

I already set the `OLEDBConnection.BackgroundQuery = False,` 
Checking for `Application.CalculationState` or 
`Application.CommandBars.GetEnabledMso("RefreshStatus")` doesn't work either.

```
Sub ShortV()
    Sheet1.Unprotect
    ActiveWorkbook.Connections(1).Refresh
    Sheet1.Protect
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Protect your worksheet using the parameter `UserInterFaceOnly:=True` so the protection does only affect the user interface but not any VBA code. That means VBA can edit the protected worksheets while the user cannot.

You can then run `.Refresh` with VBA **even on a protected worksheet**.

```
.Protect Password:="passw", UserInterFaceOnly:=True
```

You might need to do the protection of the worksheet on (re)-opening of the workbook (eg `Workbook_Open()` event). See [VBA Excel: Sheet protection: UserInterFaceOnly gone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38353751/vba-excel-sheet-protection-userinterfaceonly-gone)

Comment: @jan A I have clarified my explanation. See this answer again.

Comment: hm, could you tell me on which point you use UserInterFaceOnly:=True in the code? Maybe I did it wrong.

Comment: In the [Worksheet.Protect method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.protect) that you use to protect your sheet. Don't protect your sheet manually protect it using the `Workbook_Open()` event.

Comment: @PEH: the error message in my german version is: "Der Download wurde nicht abgeschlossen" [roughly translated: the download was not completed] even if I am writing UserInterFaceOnly:=True before the .refresh. I`m getting a little bit desperate about it. Usually I find solutions to my problems within minutes, this one took me already days...

Comment: @PEH: I unprotected my sheet, then protected it with UserInterFaceOnly:=True, then ran my code to refresh, still the same result. :/

Comment: Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20349607/protect-excel-worksheet-for-read-only-but-enable-external-data-refresh

Comment: Thank you again. It still doesn`t work. The code of the link boils down to my 5 lines of code with UserInterFaceOnly:=True added. If I comment the .protect out everythings works fine.