# Excel: problem with deleting .Connections in a protected workbook

Tags: excel, connection, protected

While trying to remove external connections from my protected Workbook (which imports data from a csv file) with VBA, I run into Runtime error '5'. Strangely, it works if I unprotect the Workbook.

I found this thread: [Protect Excel Worksheet For Read Only But Enable External Data Refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20349607/protect-excel-worksheet-for-read-only-but-enable-external-data-refresh), but the proposed solution of unprotecting the workbook while the scripts are running is out of the question.

Here is the code that I use to remove the external data connections:

```
Sub RemoveExternalDataConnections()

    Dim i As Long

    For i = ActiveWorkbook.Connections.Count To 1 Step -1

        ActiveWorkbook.Connections.Item(i).Delete

     Next

End Sub
```

All in one, I would like the external data connections be removed even if the workbook is protected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else - it seems that unprotecting the workbook is the easiest way. Setting up a password on a document/VBA project is not particularly safe anyway and it will not block most tech savvy users from accessing it.